# Incompatible types. Required: com.Google.firebase.storage.StorageReference Found: com.Google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save data (images) in firebase datadase.

```
 StorageReference storageReference;
```

But I got error
in this code of line.

`storageReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`

it keep saying that it's an incompitible types

```
 Required: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
  Found: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
```

I don't understand where is mistake and how to solve this problem.
 Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

**Instead of this**

```
storageReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

**Or this**

```
StorageReference storageReference;
StorageReference mStorageRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
```

Comment: when i use this app stop working (unfortunatly app has stopped)

Comment: No sir ..i am still stuck

Comment: did u try this `StorageReference mStorageRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()` @fawadkhan

Comment: yes... this is LOgcat  message ...                                                                        
   03-17 06:23:37.655 3138-3138/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcjg.zzs

Comment: `DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();` and this

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.access.fawad.uploadimage/com.access.fawad.uploadimage.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionatandroid.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()` returns `DatabaseReference` . If you need to use [StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/create-reference) you should use `FirebaseStorage` .

`StorageReference mStorageRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()`

Or for `DatabaseReference` you can use .

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```